# Problems using nested or list field in Swagger Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, swagger

I'm new using Python, I'm doing a microservice and I have a problem dealing with the document with the Swagger from the Flask library in Python. I have a process that returns a varchar2 with JSON format in the following way:

```
{"role":"string",
 "identification":"string",
 "class":"string",
 "address":{"streetNr":"string",
            "streetName":"string",
            "locality":"string",
            "city":"string",
            "stateOrProvince":"string",
            "country":"string",
            "geo":{"geometryType":"string",
                   "spatialRef":"string",
                   "geometry":[{"x":"number",
                                "y":"number",
                                "z":"number"}]}},
"geo":{"x":"number",
       "y":"number",
       "z":"number"},
"zone":[{"type":"string",
         "value":"string"}],
"properties":[{"name":"string",
               "value":"string"}]}
```

I want to leave this output in the swagger. I do not know much about how to do it, but I specified it in this way in Python:

```
geometry_format = {
    "x": fields.String,
    "y": fields.String,
    "z": fields.String
}

geo_format = {
    "geometryType": fields.String,
    "spatialRef": fields.String,
    "geometry": fields.List(fields.Nested(geometry_format))
}

properties_format = {
    "name": fields.String,
    "value": fields.String
}

address_format = {
    "streetNr": fields.String,
    "streetName": fields.String,
    "locality": fields.String,
    "city": fields.String,
    "stateOrProvince": fields.String,
    "country": fields.String,
    "geo": fields.Nested(geo_format)
}

md_respuesta = api.model('attributes', {
    "role": fields.String(required=True, description='Object Role'),
    "identification": fields.String(required=True, description='Object Id'),
    "class": fields.String(required=True, description='Object Class'),
    "address": fields.List(fields.Nested(address_format)),
    "geo": fields.List(fields.Nested(geo_format)),
    "zone": fields.String(required=True, description='Object Zone'),
    "properties": fields.List(fields.Nested(properties_format))
})
```

But it does not work. Any suggestions please? Is it wrong?

--***********************************************

Greetings guys. I already found the solution to comment in the swagger that type of elements. I show you the example.

```
ns = api.namespace('attributes', description='Retorna los atributos del elemento')

geometry_format = api.model('geometry', {
    "x": fields.String(description='Coordenada X'),
    "y": fields.String(description='Coordenada Y'),
    "z": fields.String(description='Coordenada Z')
})

geo_format = api.model('geo', {
    "geometryType": fields.String (description='Tipo de Geometria'),
    "spatialRef": fields.String(description='Referencia espacial'),
    "geometry": fields.List(fields.Nested(geometry_format))
})

address_format = api.model('address', {
    "streetNr": fields.String(description='Altura de la calle'),
    "streetName": fields.String(description='Nombre de la calle'),
    "locality": fields.String(description='Localidad de la calle'),
    "city": fields.String(description='Ciudad'),
    "stateOrProvince": fields.String(description='Estado o Provincia'),
    "country": fields.String(description='Pais'),
    "geo": fields.Nested(geo_format)
})

zone_format = api.model('zone', {
    "type": fields.String(description='Tipo'),
    "value": fields.String(description='Valor')
})

properties_format = api.model('properties', {
    "name": fields.String(required=True, description='Nombre de la propiedad'),
    "value": fields.String(required=True, description='Valor de la propiedad'),
})

md_respuesta = api.model('attributes', {
    "role": fields.String(required=True, description='Rol del objeto'),
    "identification": fields.String(required=True, description='Id del objeto'),
    "class": fields.String(required=True, description='Clase del objeto'),
    "address": fields.Nested(address_format, description='Contenedor de la direccion'),
    "geo": fields.Nested(geometry_format, description='Descripcion de los datos Geograficos'),
    "zone": fields.Nested(zone_format, description='Descripción de la zona'),
    "properties": fields.List(fields.Nested(properties_format), description='Descripcion de las propiedas del objeto')
})
```

I hope it helps those who have the same problem